# edit parse user information when logged in as other user in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using parse.com in my android application.when i visit other user's profile , i am able to follow that user but when i follow him value in following column of current logged in user's object is updated, but at the same time the user's value whom i followed is not updated 
**It Gives:**

```
06-27 05:11:44.521: E/AndroidRuntime(2459): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.
```

Here is my android code
    package com.example.wavie.parseQueryRunner;

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class FollowUserClass {
    private String id;
    private Context context;

    public FollowUserClass(String id, Context context) {
        this.id = id;
        this.context = context;

    }

    public void follow() {
        ParseUser currentUser=ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        currentUser.addUnique("following", id);
        try {
            currentUser.save();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("_User");
            query.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(e==null && object!=null){
                        object.addUnique("followers", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
                        try {
                            object.save();
                        } catch (ParseException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

in the code section constructor takes the object id of the user whom i want to follow.first it updates current logged in user adds taken id in following field(array).

then i tried to make update in other user's object by adding line

```
    object.addUnique("followers", 
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
```

but when i save it gives parse user should be authenticated before ssaving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer the next day i asked this question.that time the single way to do this is by deploying cloud code.
actually the user i wanted to update was other user so it is not possible to update someone's else information in the database.parse provides a solution to do this in android(possible in js) by deploying a cloud code on the server.
parse gives a command line tool to do this
for linux run following command to install 
curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash

after successfull installation a folder named parse will be created in home/etc/.
now type command parse $configure accountkey -d
 on terminal ,it will ask for your parse credentials.
now type parse command on terminal to select one of your existing application.
now you open main.js file in home/etc/parse edit.
switch to terminal  deploy code by using 
$parse deploy command.
now you are good to go cloud code has been deployed

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions the issue here. The user is not authenticated to perform the operation. This happens when a user updating a a row in parse is not the one who has created the respective row.

So probably you should give write access to the user who is updating the entries.